# cannot find symbol class BaseExpandableListAdapter android studio error

Tags: android, android-studio

i'm new to android studio and i'm trying to user BaseExpandableListAdapter
and while running my project it raises an error says that

Cannot find symbol class BaseExpandableListAdapter
and here is extra errors for class functions

**Error :**

```
Error:(66, 43) error: cannot find symbol class BaseExpandableListAdapter
Error:(92, 3) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(103, 3) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(113, 3) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(244, 3) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(119, 3) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(108, 3) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(249, 3) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(256, 3) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(261, 3) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(297, 3) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(304, 4) error: cannot find symbol method notifyDataSetChanged()
Error:(313, 3) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
```

my android studio version 1.1.0

Answer (score 2):

I met the same issue.

There are two solutions for this issue.
You can try it.

- **Solution 1**

Use full qualified name of that class instead of only class name.

E.g. change

```
class xxx extends BaseAdapter
```

to

```
class xxx extends android.widget.BaseAdapter
```

- **Solution 2**

Delete unused 'import' sentences.

Use **Ctrl + Alt + O**, delete unused imports quickly.

Maybe this is caused by unused imports.
Good luck.